# Webpack - Karma: test failing when trying to parse a jpg

Tags: webpack, karma-runner

I have an Angular1.6 app which uses Webpack to bundle and Karma for unit tests.   My unit tests are currently failing with the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/core/nav.template.html
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './\"/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg\"' in '/home/brian/Projects/frontend/src/app/core'
 @ ./src/app/core/nav.template.html 1:624-676
 @ ./src/app/core/nav.component.js
 @ ./src/app \.js$
 @ ./webpack.karma.context.js
```

I think this means the test can't 'read' the JPG file. When I'm browsing the page I can see the image correctly so I'm setting it up properly there but not in my karma config.  Here is the relevant section from my `webpack.conf`:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    . . .
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And part of my `karma.conf`

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: [
      'jasmine',
      'es6-shim'
    ],
    files: [
      'webpack.karma.context.js',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      'webpack.karma.context.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(jpe?g)$/i,
            loaders: [
              'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
              'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
          'window.$': 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
          moment: 'moment',
          jstree: 'jstree'
        })
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you running webpack 1.x? Why `basePath` is `''` ?

Comment: @Ematipico it is Webpack 2.2.1. What else would `basePath` be?

Comment: Karma uses `basePath` as starting point to read your files/configuration/everything. Have you tried to set it as the same value you have in your dev webpack config?